# MKAnnotation - Multiple annotations not appearing

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I wrote a test application for a `MKMapView` after having problems with my application. My problem is that I cannot place multiple pins on a map. Using this code in a `viewDidLoad:` method, 10 pins SHOULD show up, in a diagonal from the coordinate specified:

```
Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    annotation.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pin%i", i];
    annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.41181 + (i * .1), -122.11809 + (i * .1));
    [array addObject:annotation];
}
[map addAnnotations:array];
```

`Annotation` is simply just:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *subtitle;
@property(nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

-(id)init;

@end


@implementation Annotation
@synthesize title, subtitle, coordinate;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

Instead of seeing 10 pins, I only see my 'current location' and one pin, far away, that has title and subtitle of "Pin9", and "9". It seems that it only adds the most recent element in the array.

Can someone see what's going on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling a little bit, I found out that it works if you place the line:

```
Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
```

INSIDE the `for` loop, not outside.
Oh well, live and learn.

Comment: Well, thats cause outside of the For Loop, you are only creating a single Annotation and reassigning it every loop. When you place inside the loop, you are creating a new Annotation for each loop and adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Annotation must be allocated within for loop.

Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];

Comment: Don't you mean:
`Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];`